# aws cloudfront access denied on public s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a cloudfront distribution configured to serve from 2 origins

1. S3 Bucket
   This is for `myapp/*` and has precedence 0
2. ELB endpoint
   This is for `*` and has precedence 1

The S3 is for static content and has 24hours TTL while the ELB endpoint has dynamic content and has a 0 TTL.

However, when I try to access the resource using `https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/myapp/1.js` it says `Access Denied`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>A5774CE6B9F6Aaa3</RequestId>
  <HostId>ALA3x7kLwTVdCsakaaaaVTHP++0cBoue0FOJweanUYwdDZoqaW6i7FWA7eZYq4HVVRITa8rBwC0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The same file is served using the S3 endpoint: `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myapp-bucket/1.js`

The `myapp-bucket` is public.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does it help if you place 1.js in folder myapp (in your bucket)?

Comment: hmm, i can try that. i tried setting `/` as my origin path but that is removed by aws. Do I really have to put my files in `myapp` dir? :/

Comment: I am not sure, but from looking at the AWS CF console, I would say so. After all, you are trying to reach `/myapp/1.js`

Comment: huh, that worked. But when I tried to use my elb endpoint, CF says it cannot connect to the origin. ideas?

Comment: ELB is in the same account and has healthy instances?

Comment: yeah, healthy instances and same account.

Comment: Does ELB security group allow access from CF?

Comment: If **you** can connect directly to the origin ELB with your browser, and the security group is allowing access from `0.0.0.0/0` to port 443 (assuming SSL) then it probably is not that CloudFront "can't" connect, but rather that it refuses to connect, because the origin does not offer a valid SSL certificate.  CloudFront is not integrated with ELBs so it needs to validate that your origin server is not an impostor, which means the SSL cert must be from a trusted CA with a subject name matching either the origin hostname or the HTTP `Host` header in the request.